# Powershell - add to array without echoing index

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm adding items to an array called $MissingIps using the following command

```
    $MissingIps = @("")
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ExistingIps = $MissingIps
    if ($lbips -notcontains $awsip){
        $MissingIps.Add("$awsip")
    }
```

On execution, powershell automatically echos the index position, and I'm struggling to hide that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `| out-null` to the line where you want to hide the output.